# The vue component does not rerender

Tags: vue.js

I received a value from the server but it does not appear in the output. I tried component keys or force updates, but to no avail.

```
export default {
  data() {
      return{
          msg: null,
          componentkey: 0,
      }
  },
      async mounted() {
      try{
          let response =await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/process')
          this.msg = response.data
          this.componentkey += 1;
      }
      catch (err) {
          // eslint-disable-next-line
          console.log(err)
      }
    },
};
```

Oh, and I'm referencing the server without being updated, can you tell me about this?

Comment: What do you mean by _"it does not appear in the output"_? Which parts do not appear, only some or all of your `msg` properties?

Comment: The front end page does not re-render. 
Json {data} => msg

Comment: The `componentkey` is not needed here to re-render. So there are no errors in the console?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem ~ https://jsfiddle.net/smtau73y/

Comment: There is no error in the console.
Is there a good way to force vue rendering?

Comment: ```{
  "file_name": "2.jpg", 
  "font_color": "red", 
  "info_text": "\uc720\ud574 \uc774\ubbf8\uc9c0\ub85c \ud310\ubcc4\ub418\uc5c8\uc2b5\ub2c8\ub2e4.", 
  "part_name": "(pennis)", 
  "rate_adult": "0.63", 
  "rate_part": "0.99"
}
```

Comment: @unyeol You should at least get `TypeError: msg is null` from your code.

Comment: ```return{
          msg: '   ',```

Comment: I know you just want to have you values rendered so you will think force rendering will be the option but the solution can be as simple as using `msg: {},` in data.

Comment: @A1rPun even with `msg: null`, it still works (as can be seen in my JSFiddle example above) but it does show that warning so yes, OP should use `msg: {}`

Comment: It's been a while since I used stack overflow. Do you know where to send?

Comment: @unyeol it's actually impossible that there are no errors in your console. As pointed out, this should be showing a warning about _"msg is null"_ so could you please go back to your console and report any and all errors you see

Comment: @Phil Sorry. I was wrong There is an error. I'll update now.

Comment: @Phil Yeah you are right. Never knew it was just a warning, I assumed red = error, orange = warning :). Errors will cancel JavaScript execution therefore your values won't get rendered.

Comment: @A1rPun Can you see what it means? Sorry I'm a beginner.

Comment: It's probably your image. Make it conditional with`v-if`

Comment: @Phil 
Are you saying to reconfigure with v-if?

Comment: I mean `<img v-if="msg && msg.file_name" :src=...`

Comment: ```<img v-if= "msg.info_text && msg.font_color && msg.file_name" :src=...>``` 
Thank you, but still not reflected.

Comment: My guess seems to be related to asynchronous update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't need to bind the "key" attribute to the div tag. The "key" attribute is like an identity data for Vue to mark up the DOM which is created through the "v-for" loop.